# is there a way to allow Xcode to access the desktop once and for all?

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

I am a novel about the programming. I start using Xcode for a Computer Vision school project. I created the folders of the project with the CMake tool, and I perform the code with Xcode, everything works but every time I compile/run the code with Xcode, the system asks me to allow the project folder to access the desktop. It is not a big problem but, it is a bit annoying to allow this access every time I compile the code. Is there a way to, in somehow allow the Xcode project to access the system folders once and not every time?.

I am using OS X Catalina, 10.15.4[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kHsI.png)

Comment: it should ask even if you grant the entitlement for each signed build you make.  what is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't ask for permission every time.

For a template workaround, you could remove App Sandbox capability during debug.